# If player#1 hold a pair and player#2 can make 2 pair using the board, whos wins?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Ok so if the player#1 holds (A)(A) and player#2 holds a (3)(6) and the board has (K)(7)(3)(7)(6). Who wins?

Answer (score 0):

Poker hands have EXACTLY FIVE CARDS: no more, no less. Player 1's best five-card hand is A-A-7-7-K, two pair, aces over sevens. Player 2's best five-card hand is 7-7-6-6-K, two pair, sevens and sixes. Player 1 wins. There's no such thing as "three pair", because that would require six cards, and only five cards count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the best five cards you can get from the seven cards in front of you(2 in your hands) and the 5 cards of the board.

Next you need to understand the rank of poker hands.

In your example, Player 1 wins since his hand will be ***AA77K*** and other player's hand would be ***7766K***.

Although, in this particular example it is not possible for player 2 to have flush, it is worth mentioning that the suit of the cards plays an important role, since player 2 here could have won, if he has 5 cards of the same suit (Flush ranks higher than two pair).